# Tkinter app freezing when using threaded class

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on a app that simulates work. I have a Tkinter class and a separate class that is threaded. When I click a button it simulates the work by calling the threaded class. But my GUI still freezes I was wondering why that is and how I can fix it. I also know this is a very similar to another question on here but I tried their fix and it did not work.

```
from threading import Thread
from Tkinter import *
import socket

class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.pack()

        self.test()

    def test(self):
        it = Button(text="Hi", command=self.click)
        it.pack()

    def click(self):
        Connect(1).start()

class Connect(Thread):
    def __init__(self, num):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        while True:
            print("1")

if "__Main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Frozen Cloud")
    root.geometry("600x400")

    gui = GUI(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Rename `Connect.test()` to `Connect.run()` and remove  calling `test()` in `__init__()`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you this worked perfectly I am curious how is the run function being launched without being called?

Comment: @cdw100100: Read about [Thread.start and Thread.run](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start)

Comment: @cdw100100 It is because `start()` will call `run()`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you for all the help buddy!